# How can I get the data from Strapi backend to display on the front end

Tags: vue.js, strapi

I have a strapi backend platform with a Vue front end. I'm trying to display content on the front page, but I'm having an issue.

It's calling in the data no problem and displays it in the console.log when I put one in. However, in the Vue data, the array remains empty so it won't display the data at all. Is there something I'm missing in my script on the page I want it to display? Below is the specific script code.

Again, the return within the try/catch actually shows the data. It's the return in the Vue data that doesn't want to populate

```
<script>
import Vue from "vue";
export default {
  name: "whatsNew",
  
  async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    try {
   
      var WhatsNew = await Vue.$whatsNewService.findOne(to.params.id);
  
      return next((vm) => {
        vm.WhatsNew = WhatsNew;
        console.log(WhatsNew.title);
      });
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      next(false);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      whatsNew: [],
    };
  },

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this instance, everything was right aside from a major gaffe...capitlization of whatsNew in the return. WhatsNew solved it

Comment: Your code exposes you to a potential problem with reactivity - replacing the `whatsNew[]` in the data hook with the object returned from `findOne` - better to push these documents into the existing array. So replace `vm.whatsNew = whatsNew` with `vm.whatsNew.push(...whatsNew)` - then you simply append the new items in the returned array onto the existing array, avoiding potential problems with reactivity that might be caused by replacing the original array. Doing it this way is compliant with Vue's reactivity system.

Comment: @TremendusApps thank you for the advice. I really appreciate that!

Comment: @TremendusApps when doing that suggestion, however, I get a invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. Not sure if that's just missing something small or what it could be

Comment: Then the whatsNew returned from the API call is not an array - inspect this in console.